# C# Add circle on hit test

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a working mouse click event on my windows form graph and now I'd like to add data points on each click to make it visible where on the graph it was clicked. Upon the 3rd click, the previous 2 will clear and the 3rd and 4th click will have their own new data points and so on and so on (2 data points at a time to show start and stop locations and the difference/delta is calculated between those to positions).

My current code looks like:

```
private void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    HitTestResult result = chart1.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);

    if (result.PointIndex >= 0)
    {
        if (diffCounter == 0)
        {
            xOne = result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex].YValues[0];
            diffCounter++;
            //Console.WriteLine("VALY " + xOne);
        }
        else if (diffCounter == 1)
        {
            xTwo = result.Series.Points[result.PointIndex].YValues[0];
            diffCounter = 0;
            //Console.WriteLine("Delta = " + Math.Round(Math.Abs(xTwo - xOne)), 2);
            pointDifferenceTextBox.Text = Math.Round((Math.Abs(xTwo - xOne)), 2).ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

I cannot find anything anywhere about adding a data point based on where a hit test was performed on a line chart (or any chart for that matter).

Difference `Counter` is just an `int` to determine whether its the first or second click.

`xOne` is to get the first click y-value, `xTwo` is to get the second click y-value.

EDIT: I'd like to had a circle data point based on where the hit test is performed on.

Comment: So, you are using a chart control?  Have you done a search on how to add points to chart controls?  You would find things like https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/3a3a067a-34cd-47fb-97c5-60931d19b986/how-adding-a-datapoint-to-a-chart-control-fastpoint-type-at-run-time?forum=MSWinWebChart

Comment: So, is the chart set up? I.e. did you set max and in values for both axes so you see the axes correctly?

Comment: I just edited my post and added a screen shot. I'd like a data point (circle) added to wherever the user has selected on the chart.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the post was changed a new answer seems warranted.

Here is how one can create two points to be drawn in a `Paint` event.

First we need to store them:

```
PointF p1 = PointNull;
PointF p2 = PointNull;
```

To flag state we also use a static value:

```
static PointF PointNull = new PointF(-123f, -123f);
```

You could use some other flag as well in order to control switching between the 1st and 2nd point.

Next we need to store values in the click :

```
private void chart1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{

    Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

    double x = ax.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
    double y = ay.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);

    y = GetMedianYValue(chart1.Series[0], x);

    if (p1 == PointNull ||(p1 != PointNull && p2 != PointNull))
    {
        p1 = new PointF((float)x, (float)y);
        p2 = PointNull;
    }
    else
    {
        p2 = new PointF((float)x, (float)y);
    }
    // values have changed, trigger drawing them!
    chart1.Invalidate();
}
```

Note that I first use the axis functions to get the axis values of the clicked position. Then I overwrite the y-value by a function that calculates the point on the line..:

```
double GetMedianYValue(Series s,  double xval )
{
    // Findclosest datapoints:
    DataPoint dp1 =  s.Points.Where(x => x.XValue <= xval).LastOrDefault();
    DataPoint dp2 =  s.Points.Where(x => x.XValue >= xval).FirstOrDefault();

    // optional
    dp1.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
    dp1.MarkerColor = Color.Purple;
    dp2.MarkerStyle = MarkerStyle.Circle;
    dp2.MarkerColor = Color.Violet;

    double dx = dp2.XValue - dp1.XValue;
    double dy = dp2.YValues[0] - dp1.YValues[0];
    // same point
    if (dx == 0) return dp1.YValues[0];
    // calculate median
    double d = dp1.YValues[0] + dy / dx * ( xval - dp1.XValue) ;
    return d;
}
```

Note that this function **marks** the neighbouring datapoints for **testing** only!

Finally we need to draw the two points:

```
private void chart1_PostPaint(object sender, ChartPaintEventArgs e)
{
    Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
    Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

    int x1 = (int)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(p1.X);
    int y1 = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(p1.Y);
    int x2 = (int)ax.ValueToPixelPosition(p2.X);
    int y2 = (int)ay.ValueToPixelPosition(p2.Y);

    if (x1 >= 0 && x1 < chart1.Width)  // sanity check
        if (p1 != PointNull)
            e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.LightSeaGreen, x1 - 3, y1 - 3, 6, 6);

    if (x2 >= 0 && x2 < chart1.Width)  // sanity check
        if (p2 != PointNull)
            e.ChartGraphics.Graphics.DrawEllipse(Pens.Red, x2 - 3, y2 - 3, 6, 6);
}
```

Here is the result:

[image]

Comment: THIS is what I'm looking for. Thank you very much for your assistance. I was about to post my solution that I came up with but yours seems much better as it'll just to the closest point in the line which I now see what you were originally talking about.

Answer (score 0):

The original post asked for adding a `DataPoint` at the clicked location. For this `HitTest` is not useful.

Instead you need one of the the [**axis functions**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.datavisualization.charting.axis?view=netframework-4.7.2); `PixelPositionToValue` will **convert** the **pixels** position to an axis **value**..:

```
Axis ax = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisX;
Axis ay = chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY;

double x = ax.PixelPositionToValue(e.X);
double y = ay.PixelPositionToValue(e.Y);

DataPoint dp = new DataPoint(x, y);
dp.Color = Color.Red;
chart1.Series[0].Points.Add(dp);
```

Note that these function are **only valid** in either one of the **paint** or one of the **mouse** events!

Comment: This actually adds a point to whatever is in the series and gets rid of whatever is after the point I click. Maybe I'm asking the wrong question. What if I just want to DRAW a circle wherever the user clicks. But the circles can only be somewhere on the line and not just randomly on the chart itself. After 2 circles are drawn, they'd need to be cleared.

Comment: Your title and question clearly states several times that you want to add a DataPoint! And, no, it doesn't 'get rid' of anything. So, where do you want the circles drawn? At the click or on the line? x=click and y=line?

Comment: Yes, I'm aware my title is different and that is because my understanding of a data point must be wrong. I just want some sort of circle placed wherever the hit test finds a point based in the series. If I click the line, the hit test then has some sort of value in the series; I want a circle placed where this hit test is placed.

Comment: Well, a DataPoint is a chart elenent. Simply drawing a 1-2 circles can be done in a simlar way. I'll show you, but you need to think this through: What should happen when the user clicks somewhere else, not on or even close to the lines?? Also: the lines consist of datapoints which may be close but also may be far apart... Shall the circles sit on the closest datapoint or can they sit in between??

Comment: Well I know a hit test doesn't "register" if you don't click on the line so I'd like something similar. If the user clicks somewhere random on the chart where a line isn't close, then the circle shouldn't appear. I want to use it as an indication of where the user has clicked. You are correct that the data points may be close or far apart but the line has decimal figures so they should be allowed to sit in between I'm guessing to answer that part of the question.

Comment: Yes, the questions are answered, but the answers contradict each other. If you click between two points the hittest will fail!

Comment: I'm confused as to what you mean by it'll fail? Because it is registering for me just fine as I'm using the hit test to do some calculations as well, which work fine.

Comment: It will always register something but it will only point to a datapoint __(i.e. PointIndex>= 0)__ if you actually hit a point, not somewhere between two points! Maybe your points are so dense you always hit one? Hint: It is a good idea to code the mousemove event to change the Cursor to, say, Cross when a point is being hit..

Comment: Well, maybe the best solution is ti simply mark you DataPoints. You can set a MarkerStyle or simply change their color or both..